# How to change a resource icon in a imageview with another resource icon

Tags: android, resources, imageview

I have been reading some post about changing an image in an ImageView.
But everyone asks for setting an ImageView with a custom image, and I want to set a system image inside it.

I made this:

```
ledicon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.presence_busy));
```

But Eclipse tells me that presence_busy is not recognized.
Why?

I am using presence_online in the XML file,

```
android:src="@android:drawable/presence_online"
```

and all works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ledicon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.presence_busy));
```

(When accessing system resouces you have to look them um in android.R not your own.)

Comment: 10 minutes ^^. Wait ;)